# Computers won't boot from an SSD but all files are detected

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd

last night when my girlfriend was over, she pressed the power button on my desktop five or six times to try and turn it off. This morning, the computer wouldn't boot, and I got a read error from the drive when I plugged it into my laptop. However, when I booted the laptop from another drive, it read the SSD just fine. I can see and access all the data that's stored on it. What do I do? Do I just need to update the firmware or something? SSD in question is a Crucial M4 128GB.

Comment: No; Upgrading the firmware will not solve your problem;

Comment: So then is there any way to fix it or is it completely screwed?

Comment: Maybe try fixing the MBR or GTP.

Comment: The first thing to do is get anything off of that drive which you may want. After that, you can try the repair steps mentioned by Neo. If that doesn't work (or even if it does) I'd say that you'd be best to reformat. This drive might not be a good boot drive. If that is the only problem then I'd just use it as a fast data drive for non essential data until it dies (a game drive for example). If it does that OK for awhile then you can probably start using it normally again.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try this method:
Put the windows DVD in to your machine, and restart it, and press f11 or f12 (so you must be enter to boot mode)
After you can enter repair mode and you can select the command mode like in this picture:
[image]

And as the image is saided, type this command in to command prompt:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

(I'm feel so lucky for this image on Google :D)
Edit:
Oh I almost forget it:
If you can, make a backup with Ubuntu Live CD (also can be started with f11-f12) and reboot it.
Also you can enter the safe mode (press f8) and select safe mode with command promt.
Now type this in tho prompt:

```
chkdsk/f
```